# open vistadb vdb file

Tags: vistadb

I have a database file with the extension "vdb" - presumably this is a VistaDB file - anyone know what to use to open it and access the tables inside?

Answer (score 0):

If that really is a VistaDB database, it would be VistaDB 2.  You can't get that version anymore, but the VistaDB 3 migration wizard can get the data out of it.

If this is something you need for your company contact us by opening a support ticket at VistaDB.net.